# Как сделать свой поиск в wordpress по названию таксономии?

Tags: wordpress

Есть пользовательский тип записи "Запчасть", к нему таксономия "Модель".
Как сделать свой поиск, и вставлять по шорткоду?

Поиск должен работать так:
Ввести в инпут поиска "ms1200" (модель), ищет по названию таксономии!, и выдает результаты всех запчастей, в таксономии модели (ms1200).

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Mini-Shop
Description: Мини-магазин запчастей.
Version: 1.0
Author: Влад Неверов
*/

add_shortcode('mini-shop', function ()
{
    return get_shop_search_form();
});

add_action('init', function ()
{
    register_post_type('part',
    [
        'label'  => 'Запчасть',
        'labels' => [
            'name'               => 'Запчасть', // основное название для типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Запчасть', // название для одной записи этого типа
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить запчасть', // для добавления новой записи
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление запчасти', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование запчасти', // для редактирования типа записи
            'new_item'           => 'Новая запчасть', // текст новой записи
            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть запчасть', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
            'search_items'       => 'Искать запчасть', // для поиска по этим типам записи
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
            'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
            'menu_name'          => 'Запчасти', // название меню
        ],
        'description'         => 'Запчасти в мини-магазине',
        'public'              => true,
        // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
        // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
        // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
        // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
        'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
        // 'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // зависит от show_in_menu
        'show_in_rest'        => true, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
        'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
        'menu_position'       => null,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-tools',
        //'capability_type'   => 'post',
        //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
        //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'supports'            => [ 'title', 'editor' ], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
        'taxonomies'          => ['model'],
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
    ]);

    register_taxonomy('model', ['part'], 
    [ 
        'label'                 => 'Модель',
        'labels'                => [
            'name'              => 'Модель',
            'singular_name'     => 'Модель',
            'search_items'      => 'Поиск по модели',
            'all_items'         => 'Все модели',
            'view_item '        => 'Просмотреть модель',
            'parent_item'       => 'Родительская модель',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Родительская модель:',
            'edit_item'         => 'Редактировать модель',
            'update_item'       => 'Обновить модель',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить модель',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Название модели',
            'menu_name'         => 'Модели',
        ],
        'description'           => 'Модели и серийные номера', // описание таксономии
        'public'                => true,
        // 'publicly_queryable'    => null, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_ui'               => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_menu'          => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        // 'show_tagcloud'         => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        // 'show_in_quick_edit'    => null, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'model', // ярлык
            'hierarchical' => false // разрешить вложенность
        ],
        // 'query_var'             => $taxonomy, // название параметра запроса
        'capabilities'          => [],
        'meta_box_cb'           => null, // html метабокса. callback: `post_categories_meta_box` или `post_tags_meta_box`. false — метабокс отключен.
        'show_admin_column'     => false, // авто-создание колонки таксы в таблице ассоциированного типа записи. (с версии 3.5)
        'show_in_rest'          => true, // добавить в REST API
        // 'rest_base'             => null, // $taxonomy
        // '_builtin'              => false,
        //'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    ]);

});

function get_shop_search_form($args = [])
{
    /**
     * Fires before the search form is retrieved, at the start of get_search_form().
     *
     * @since 2.7.0 as 'get_search_form' action.
     * @since 3.6.0
     *
     * @link https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19321
     */
    do_action( 'pre_get_search_form' );

    $echo = true;

    if ( ! is_array( $args ) ) {
        /*
         * Back compat: to ensure previous uses of get_search_form() continue to
         * function as expected, we handle a value for the boolean $echo param removed
         * in 5.2.0. Then we deal with the $args array and cast its defaults.
         */
        $echo = (bool) $args;

        // Set an empty array and allow default arguments to take over.
        $args = [];
    }

    // Defaults are to echo and to output no custom label on the form.
    $defaults = [
        'echo'       => $echo,
        'aria_label' => '',
    ];

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    /**
     * Filters the array of arguments used when generating the search form.
     *
     * @since 5.2.0
     *
     * @param array $args The array of arguments for building the search form.
     */
    $args = apply_filters( 'search_form_args', $args );

    $format = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'search-form' ) ? 'html5' : 'xhtml';

    /**
     * Filters the HTML format of the search form.
     *
     * @since 3.6.0
     *
     * @param string $format The type of markup to use in the search form.
     *                       Accepts 'html5', 'xhtml'.
     */
    $format = apply_filters( 'search_form_format', $format );

    $search_form_template = locate_template( 'searchform.php' );
    if ( '' != $search_form_template ) {
        ob_start();
        require $search_form_template;
        $form = ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        // Build a string containing an aria-label to use for the search form.
        if ( isset( $args['aria_label'] ) && $args['aria_label'] ) {
            $aria_label = 'aria-label="' . esc_attr( $args['aria_label'] ) . '" ';
        } else {
            /*
             * If there's no custom aria-label, we can set a default here. At the
             * moment it's empty as there's uncertainty about what the default should be.
             */
            $aria_label = '';
        }
        if ( 'html5' == $format ) {
            $form = '<form role="search" ' . $aria_label . 'method="get" class="search-form" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</span>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder' ) . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) . '" />
            </form>';
        } else {
            $form = '<form role="search" ' . $aria_label . 'method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) . '</label>
                    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="' . esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) . '" />
                </div>
            </form>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filters the HTML output of the search form.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     *
     * @param string $form The search form HTML output.
     */
    $result = apply_filters( 'get_search_form', $form );

    if ( null === $result ) {
        $result = $form;
    }

    if ( $args['echo'] ) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: И где код поиска?

Comment: @Krya вопрос и заключается в том, как сделать свой поиск по таксономиям

Comment: @laravelcode У вас ни строчки кода связанного с поиском, за вас код никто не будет писать.

Comment: @Krya добавил код поиска

Comment: @laravelcode хорошо, а как пользователь будет указывать таксономию?

Comment: @Krya в админке в таксономии "модели", создается ms1200, в записях "запчасти", создаются записи, и указывается - ms1200. В инпуте поиска, нужно всего лишь написать название рубрики ms1200, и в результатах поиска выдать все запчасти, которые из таксономии ms1200.

я пробовал добавить в форму поиска:
`<input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" value="model">`
Но это не работает с таксономиями